# How to edit lightdm to show "other user"?

Tags: permissions, lightdm, active-directory

I am an IT student aide at a college and we have a very small test computer that we started messing around on with 12.04 and used likewise to join it into the Windows network that we have.

However, we are trying to get it to show the "other user" for the manual log on but the **lightdm** folder with `lightdm.conf` files are read-only.

How would I be able to change that so I can write to this file?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this as root as peachy said, but I have a simpler option that you can use besides an editor, you can do this using **lightdm-set-defaults**.

This will show the "Other" user:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --show-manual-login true
```

This will disable the user list, if you just want to see "Other":

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults  --hide-users true
```

And lastly you can turn off guest:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults  --allow-guest false
```

Doing this you end up with only "Other", or you can just use the first line I posted to add it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the `lightdm.conf` as root in order to make changes to it.

**Method 1: Via Terminal**

1. Launch the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Run this command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
   ```
3. This will open the `lightdm.conf` in gedit. Make the necessary modifications you want to the file.
4. Save and close it.

**Method 2: Via Nautilus**

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
2. Type **gksu nautilus** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type your password.
4. Nautilus will be launched. You can now browse to **File System → etc → lightdm**
5. Open the `lightdm.conf` and make the necessary modifications you want to the file.
6. Save and close it.